# WinDbg showing same lines multiple times

Tags: windbg

I'm having readability issues with WinDbg, it outputs same lines 2 or more times over and over again, spamming out the console.

Here is an example snapshot of WinDbg output:

```
Built by: 17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
Built by: 17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
Machine Name:Machine Name:

Kernel base = 0xfffff800`eb41e000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`eb7d81f0
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`eb41e000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`eb7d81f0
Debug session time: Tue Jul 31 03:55:51.667 2018 (UTC + 2:00)
Debug session time: Tue Jul 31 03:55:51.667 2018 (UTC + 2:00)

Loading Kernel Symbols
Loading Kernel Symbols

Loading User Symbols
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.Loading unloaded module list
```

as you can see, it duplicates lines, do you know what could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: afaik this used to happen when some extensions forgot to release the release registered output callback it appears you have the latest windbg  try downgrading your windbg to say 16299 or 17063

Comment: it somehow stopped to display multiple lines after some time of usage and pc restarts.

Comment: edit: it works fine if restarting windbg for each crashdump, otherwise it multiplies lines depending on how many crash dumps I open in same session.

Comment: Restarting WinDbg is enough. Did you use the SOS extension before?

Comment: no, I don't even know what that is.

Comment: sometimes .restart did resolve it for me but most of the time I had to restart the debugger. I haven't seen it with the new beta version in the windows store

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen when some extensions forget to unregister their output callbacks.

Restart WinDbg after every debugging session or try the new [WinDbg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) from Microsoft Store. It has a better usability anyway.