# Windbg x64 commands being ran twice after being entered once

Tags: debugging, windbg

I opened a mini dump and ran !analyze
then ran qd to close it and detach

I opened another mini dump
Now i run !analyze but it shows on command window twice and each line for output is duplicated.

Is there something else I should be doing to close / end the crash dump?

```
0:029> !analyze
0:029> !analyze
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
```

windbg 10.0.19041.085   win 10 pro

Comment: Always restart WinDbg after a debug session. This happens now and again since version 6. Or use [WinDbg Preview from the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703000/480982